# What does this means in this context ? 二条で殺された方がまだマシじゃ ( "I would rather die with/by ......" ??)

Tags: meaning, word-choice, reading-comprehension, japanese-to-english

[image]

**When reading, I met this sentence but I'm not sure about 1 part, hope someone can explain to me its meaning ^^**

**Context: MC's wife has cleared a path for him and his squad, so he can go through a jungle fast and stop a war between his 2 other wives ( he's in Sengoku Era and has a harem :D). After that MC said thanks to his wife and then she said this:**

主様に頼まれたら嫌とは言えぬ.

**嫌われるくらいなら二条で殺された方がまだマシじゃ** (>> I don't understand this part 二条で殺された ? I can only guess like :"I would rather die with/by...." but not sure if this is a person name or a noun that describe a brutal way of killing someone.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, 二条 is a well-known place (street) name in Kyoto. Several famous buildings existed at this location, including [Nijo Castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nij%C5%8D_Castle), but since this manga is set in the Sengoku period, this 二条 may be referring to [this one](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA%8C%E6%9D%A1%E6%96%B0%E5%BE%A1%E6%89%80) built by Oda Nobunaga.

Comment: thanks, I'm not too familiar with the JP ancient history

Comment: 二条っていうたら、place name, location っていうより、（現代では）通りの名前かな・・　一条から十条まであるうちの。

Comment: @Chocolate この質問内容ならそこはまあ詳しく触れないでいいかなと思ったのですが、現地の人的には重要ですかね…

Comment: いあ、逆に、現地以外の人から見たらどんなイメージなんやろ・・五条、錦、大宮、堀川、丸太町、とか。